# Не удается установить соединение с базой данных сервера SQL Server - C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Пишу приложение на ASP.NET MVC.

Понадобилось вывести список всех зарегистрированных юзеров. Для вывода списка решил воспользоваться `Membership.GetAllUsers()`, но получаю исключение:

> При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Ошибка при обнаружении указанного сервера или экземпляра)

Скажите какой код нужен? База данных `localdb`, пытаюсь получить список юзеров посредством `Membership.GetAllUsers()` в контроллере и передать в вид. Таблицы в базе есть, подключение проходит нормально если подключаться через объект `DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext()`. Но таким образом я не могу получить роли юзеров.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SoftwareDevelopmentCustom;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SoftwareDevelopmentCustom.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Код:

```
   using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using WebMatrix.WebData;
    using SoftwareDevelopmentCustom.Models;
    using System.Web.Security;

    namespace SoftwareDevelopmentCustom.Filters
    {
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
        public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;

            private static object _initializerLock = new object();

            private static bool _isInitialized;

            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                // Инициализация ASP.NET Simple Membership происходит один раз при старте приложения
                LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
            }

            private class SimpleMembershipInitializer // определение класса инициализатора
            {
                public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
                {
                    Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);

                    try
                    {
                        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
                        {
                            if (!context.Database.Exists())
                            {
                                // Создание базы данных SimpleMembership без применения миграции Entity Framework
                                ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                            }
                        }
                        // Настройка  ASP.NET Simple Membership
                        // 1 параметр - имя строки подключения к базе данных.
                        // 2 параметр - таблица, которая содержит информацию о пользователях
                        // 3 параметр - имя колонки в таблице, которая отвечает за хранение логина
                        // 4 параметр - autoCreateTables автоматическое создание таблиц если они не существуют в базе
                        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

                        SimpleRoleProvider roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
                        SimpleMembershipProvider membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;


                        // Проверка наличия роли Admin
                        if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin")) 
                        {
                            roles.CreateRole("Admin");
                        }
                        // Поиск пользователя с логином admin
                        if (membership.GetUser("admin", false) == null)
                        {
                            membership.CreateUserAndAccount("admin", "qwe123"); // создание пользователя
                            roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "admin" }, new[] { "Admin" }); // установка роли для пользователя
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: И как мы должны это отлаживать, не видя кода и ConnectionString?

Comment: Больше склоняюсь, что виной всему служит [connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com). Хотя бы попробовать переподключиться.

Comment: Разобрались с проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в коде, проблема в строке подключения.

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
}
```

Фактически этот код не создает подключения. Подключение выполняется в момент первого запроса, т.е. у вас это

```
if (!context.Database.Exists()){}
```

Попробуйте соединиться с базой, которая указана у вас в DefaultConnection из Visual Studio Server Explorer.